# Simple, yet buggy, jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I have been experimenting with jQuery on my own and ran into some bugs that I just can't figure out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The simple animation can be found below (with a link to jsfiddle).

Upon clicking the button, the pig is supposed to enter from the left, move forward (completing a few pirouettes along the way), and then fade out. George Costanza enters from the left and gives his applause.

Unfortunately there is nothing for George to clap for, as the pigs movements are horrendously buggy; it skips back and forth in ways I never intended. Likewise with George's movements. Also, he never seems to get all the way off the page at the end, as I intended.

Incidentally, I had no trouble with this on the computer that I wrote the animation on (using chrome in jsfiddle). Yet, on my laptop (chrome), and a friend's laptop as well (safari?), it is hopelessly buggy.

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Here's the code and a link to jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/corduroy_joy/v69st/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#pig').animate({left:'+=200px'}, 1000).animate({top:'+=10px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=10px'}, 100).animate({bottom:'+=12px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=100px'}, 690, 'linear').animate({bottom:'+=15px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=130px'}, 590, 'linear').animate({top:'+=10px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=10px'}, 100).animate({bottom:'+=12px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=100px'}, 690, 'linear').animate({top:'-=15px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=130px'}, 590, 'linear').animate({top:'+=10px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=10px'}, 100).animate({bottom:'+=12px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=100px'}, 690, 'linear').animate({top:'-=12px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=100px'}, 690, 'linear').animate({bottom:'+=15px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=130px'}, 590, 'linear').animate({bottom:'+=15px'}, 100).animate({left:'+=130px'}, 590, 'linear').fadeTo('slow', 0).animate({left:'+=200px'}, 1000, function() {$('#pig').removeAttr('style');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          });

$('#george').animate({left:'-=1px'}, 7000).animate({left:'+=280px'}, 1500).delay(1400).animate({left:'-=281px'},  3500);   
});
});
```

Update: Ugh, nothing of the endless number of things I've tried seems to work. I give up on jQuery animation!

Comment: Simple animation? really?

Comment: I suppose I should have said that this required a rather simple understanding of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the callback function of `animate` method, otherwise before an animation is  complete another animation is executed.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#pig').animate({left:'+=200px'}, 1000, function(){
        $(this).animate(..., function(){
             $(this).animate(..., function() {  })
        })
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Unfortunately, when I tried this, the animation still seemed to have the same bugs (even when I parred it down considerably). See:  http://jsfiddle.net/corduroy_joy/v69st/3/